# docker pull image got PermissionError

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

i want to run docker to run as an other user:

1. i created a user <my_user>
2. i create a group <my_group>
3. i added the user  <my_user> to the group <my_group>
4. add the user on
   "/etc/docker/daemon.json":
   {
   "userns-remap": "myuser"
   }
5. i created the file /etc/subuid with
   <my_user>:<my_user_id>:1
   <my_user>:100000:65536
6. i created the file /etc/subgid with
   <my_user>:<my_group_id>:1
   <my_user>:100000:65536
7. i restarted docker
   when i run the docker-compose pull image i got the error 'Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))2156] Failed to execute script docker-compose

and i checked with ps faux | grep docker , the service docker still running with user root

Please can you help me to resolve this issue
thank you

Comment: I think https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ helps you. Is that what you mean to run `docker blob blob` commands without `sudo`?